# Test iOS devices up against each other

Tags: ios, testing, calabash

I am planning to do some calabash testing using more than one IOS device. I want to run the tests on a mac mini, however I am not certain if it is possible to run and test more than one device using only a single mac mini. The reason I am asking this is that I have to test two or more devices up against each other. Do anyone know?

Comment: You can run separate instances of Xcode and attach each device to their Xcode. So you need to have different Xcode apps, for example, Xcode1.app, Xcode2.app etc.

Comment: That's a pretty good idea, I will try it out!

Comment: For iOS >= 7 Sergey's idea will not work because there can be only one instruments process running at once.  See this answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24476849/run-cucumber-file-on-multiple-ios-devices/24478867 Also, there is no way to start two calabash servers at the same time.  See these two items: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/pull/236 
https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/issues/176