# Run cucumber file on multiple iOS devices

Tags: cucumber, calabash-ios

How to run cucumber test on multiple devices at the same time on iOS platform(iPhone, iPad) ?

Answer (score 2):

On iOS 7 and above, this is not possible because Calabash requires the app to be launched by instruments and there can be only one instruments process alive at one time.

On iOS < 7, it is possible to test against multiple devices *iff* you manually launch the app before testing.  There might be some work-arounds to automatically launch the app on the device (there are for the simulator), but they exist outside of Calabash.  More problematic is that a significant (and growing) portion of the Calabash API *requires that the app be launched using instruments.*

On iOS < 7, use DEVICE_ENDPOINT and DEVICE_TARGET to specify which device to target.

```
# for iOS < 7 only

# device A
# launch the app manually on the device
$ DEVICE_ENDPOINT=<ip:port> DEVICE_TARGET=<udid> cucumber

# device B in another shell
# launch the app manually on the device
$ DEVICE_ENDPOINT=<ip:port> DEVICE_TARGET=<udid> cucumber
```

Comment: I am afraid that I don't understand your question.  If you are testing iOS < 7 and trying to target multiple devices, you will need to have a Terminal window for each device.